# macports on mac os x mountain lion

Tags: macports

Am trying to install macports on a newly installed mountain lion, I installed first the xCode and then installed the xCode command line tools. After that, I ran the xCode and agreed for the terms and condition, then installed the macports dmg package.

Once I did, I ran the self update command and it worked but then any self install or self upgrade won't work.

```
Mo-Mughrabis-MacBook-Pro:~ mo$ sudo port -v selfupdate
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 69 bytes  30.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3543040  speedup is 33743.24
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 76 bytes  32.00 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.57
MacPorts base version 2.1.2 installed,
MacPorts base version 2.1.2 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 70 bytes  30.29 bytes/sec
total size is 53821440  speedup is 507749.43
receiving file list ... done

sent 36 bytes  received 77 bytes  32.29 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 4.53
Creating port index in /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports

Total number of ports parsed:   0 
Ports successfully parsed:  0 
Ports failed:           0 
Up-to-date ports skipped:   15604

--->  MacPorts base is already the latest version

The ports tree has been updated. To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
  port upgrade outdated
Mo-Mughrabis-MacBook-Pro:~ mo$ sudo port upgrade outdated
Error: No ports matched the given expression
```

When i tried to run sudo port install I got the following

```
Mo-Mughrabis-MacBook-Pro:~ mo$ sudo port install 
Can't map the URL 'file://.' to a port description file ("Could not find Portfile in /Users/mo").
Please verify that the directory and portfile syntax are correct.
To use the current port, you must be in a port's directory.
```

Any one can help me out on what i might have done wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you just barely installed MacPorts, none of the actual ports (that you most likely had on another computer) have been installed yet.

If you run `port installed`, you'll notice that it returns empty.

So congratulations; 0 out of 0 ports are outdated ;-)

If you want all the same ports that you had on your other Mac(s), fire up Terminal and run `port installed` on those machines.  That should give you a list of everything, and you can either export that list, or pick-and-choose the ones you want on your new Mountain Lion installation.

And then it will be as simple as

```
port install [which program]
```

for each of those ports that you want.

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same message following this command `port clean --all`, because `MacPorts` simply found nothing to do (clean).